# what is 'mpoly' : 'MULTIPOLYGON' in Geodjango , what should be its default value if its blank

Tags: mysql, django, geodjango

I am working on example from [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contribt/gis/tutorial/][1]
using mysql as database, followed most of the steps given and while trying to load data using load.run() as in the doc, seems like

```
 # GeoDjango-specific: a geometry field (MultiPolygonField)
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()
```

is blank, **and needs a default value, what should be the default value of this field. Is it ok to keep it blank**. The data needed is :

```
world_mapping = {
    'fips' : 'FIPS',
    'iso2' : 'ISO2',
    'iso3' : 'ISO3',
    'un' : 'UN',
    'name' : 'NAME',
    'area' : 'AREA',
    'pop2005' : 'POP2005',
    'region' : 'REGION',
    'subregion' : 'SUBREGION',
    'lon' : 'LON',
    'lat' : 'LAT',
    'mpoly' : 'MULTIPOLYGON',
}
```

while command line shows this data, which does not have 'mpoly' field

```
 {'pop2005': 83039, 'region': 19, 'fips': 'AC', 'lat': 17.078, 'subregion': 29, 'name': 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'un': 28, 'iso3': 'ATG', 'iso2': 'AG', 'area': 44, 'lon': -61.783}
```

Comment: the link is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/

Comment: Now getting " AttributeError: 'WKTAdapter' object has no attribute 'translate' " error as getting  'mpoly': 'MULTIPOLYGON (((-61.686668 17.024441000000138,-61.73806 16.989719,-61.82917 16.996944,-........))'  the verbose shows this as  'mpoly' although it has more value but due to length restriction i am showing few . Please help thank you